# Sub-subsequences convergence

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

$(z_n)_n$ converges $\Rightarrow$ $\exists z \in \mathbb{C}$ such that every subseq. of $(z_n)_n$ has a convergent subseq. with limit $z$.

Sorry, but I don't know how to start — would be amazing if u could help.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: Try showing if $(x_n)$ converges to x, then any subsequence of $(x_n)$ also converges to x

Comment: Its about the sub-subsequence converging

Comment: But this would imply that the sub-subsequence converges as well.

Comment: Why would it imply that?

Comment: well a subsubsequence is just a subsequence of another sequence

Comment: To the proposer: Any sequence is a sub-sequence of itself.

Answer (score 0):

Let $(z_n)$ be a convergent sequence in $\mathbb{C}$. Clearly there exists some $z \in \mathbb{C}$ such that $\lim z_n = z$. Let $(z_{n_k})_k$ be a subsequence of $(z_n)$. Since $(z_n)$ converges, then for $ \epsilon > 0$, there exists some $N \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $|z-z_n|<\epsilon$ for $n \geq N$. Remark that $n_k \geq k$. In other words the sequence $(n_k)$ must be non-decreasing in regards to $(z_{n_k})_k$. This is by the definition of a subsequence. Let $k \geq N$. Clearly then $n_k \geq k \geq N$. Then we can say $|z-z_{n_k}|<\epsilon$ for  $k\geq N$. Therefore $(z_{n_k})_k$ converges to $z$.

Let $(z_{n_k})_k = (a_k)$, implying that $a_k=z_{n_k}.$ Using what I proved above, I can show that any subsequence of $(a_k)$, which is actually a sub-subsequence of $(z_n)$, must also converge to $z$.

Now what I did was prove that for any convergent sequence, all subsequences are also convergent and in fact converge to the same limit. You can also show any sub-subsequence is also a subsequence.